# Conpress the JSON data inside tag attribute

Tags: html, xml, json, compression

I am using a tag attribute `data` to handle some JSON data inside a html tag:

```
<div data="%22%3A%22%D0%B1%D1...">The text..</data>
```

My problem is increasing the size of JSON string after encoding:

```
var json = {
    a:"letter a", 
    b:"буква &laquo;бэ&raquo;"
},
attr = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(json));
```

As result of execution, the code produces tag with long attribute:

```
<div data ="%7B%22a%22%3A%22letter%20a%22%2C%22b%22%3A%22%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%26laquo%3B%D0%B1%D1%8D%26raquo%3B%22%7D"></div>
```

The expanding ratio for this short example is 2.8

Might be there is the ways to compress the data with the final ratio under 2.0?

Comment: Is it necessary for the data to be present in the DOM? If not, it might be easier to keep the JSON data in JS and use an identifier to mark DOM-element and the corresponding data. E.g. using `mydata[id] = {}` for data storage in JS, where `id` is the id-attribute of the `<div>`.

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case, I have no single chance to avoid keep the data inside the tag. No `script`, no external source, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Lempel-Ziv-Welch (LZW) algorithm for JavaScript](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/LZW_compression#JavaScript)

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RPcuq/)</kbd>

Compression is excellent for the big data blocks and useless for short JSON with couple lines. Therefore, the best balance of using the compression is to have a choice "compress or not compress" for every case.

Example for the big data (long JSON):

`<div compression="lzw" data="7e9145d1890181fdb617...">...</div>`

Example the short JSON:

`<div compression="none" data="88%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D...">...</div>`